# How do I capture data piped to a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

If I call a script like this

`echo "some text" | myscript`

How do I capture "some text" in the script to work with.  In this case maybe to assign it to a variable.

I've been searching on Google, but I think I'm not using the correct terminology to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you asking how to use stdin in your script ?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not certain on that.  I'm not familiar with stdin as far as scripting goes.  Normally I use arguments for my scripts, but due to what I'm trying to do here, that's not an option for this particular case.

Comment: It looks like it, though I stuck it in a while loop so I could get it all in a single variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the data from previous command (`echo` in your case) will be available on STDIN of next command in pipeline. Just use `read` built-in to capture it. Here is a way to capture a single line using `read:

```
echo "some text" | { IFS= read -r line; echo "line=[$line]"; }
line=[some text]
```

Or you can even use default `REPLY` variable:

```
echo "some text" | { IFS= read -r; echo "line=[$REPLY]"; }
line=[some text]
```

Comment: Leading and trailing white-spaces won't be read with out `IFS=`

Comment: It can done in a sub-shell also in `echo "some text  " | ( IFS= read -r line; echo "line=[$line]"; )`

Comment: If you use the default `REPLY` variable, you don't need to set `IFS`, because `read` won't do any word-splitting that would discard leading and trailing whitespace.